# How to trigger a fake call with react native without using Voip?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

Just want to make an UI and call even the app is closed.

'''I've tried CallKeep but I doesn't work'''

Comment: Will you please provide more information about what you are wanting/what issues you are having?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have problem with code just I want to create a button that calls a function after 10 seconds and when i exit app it will trigger a fake call even if I'm not inside app